# Localstorage not updating

Tags: javascript, html

I have build a table that builds itself from the data in my Localstorage, but when I change the objects Email it isn't changing it in the table? I really can't figure out why, does anybody have an idea? I know localstorage isn't the best option, but for now I am now allowed to use any databasee.

```
    constructor(name, gender, department, yy, email, skills) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.department = department;
        this.email = email;
        this.skills = [];

    }

}

//Employee Database "Localstorage"
if(localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null) {
    var employeeList = [];
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Simon", "Male", "HR", 1999, "SM@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Mads", "Male","IT", 1999,  "MS@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Jessica", "Female", "Sales",1998, "JT@cbs.dk"));
    employeeList.push (new Employee("Benjamin", "Male","IT", 1997, "BN@cbs.dk"));

    var employeeListString = JSON.stringify(employeeList);
    localStorage.setItem("Employee", employeeListString);
    document.querySelector('#employees').appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
} else {
    var employeeList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employee"));
}

//Function creates table for employeeList
function buildTable(data) {
    let table = document.createElement("table");

        // Create table head and body
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("thead"));
        table.appendChild(document.createElement("tbody"));

        let fields = Object.keys(data[0]);
        let headRow = document.createElement("tr");
        fields.forEach(function (field) {
            let headCell = document.createElement("th");
            headCell.textContent = field;
            headRow.appendChild(headCell);
        });
        table.querySelector("thead").appendChild(headRow);
        data.forEach(function (object) {
            let row = document.createElement("tr");
            fields.forEach(function (field) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                cell.textContent = object[field];
                if (typeof object[field] == "number") {
                    cell.style.textAlign = "left";
                }
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });
            table.querySelector("tbody").appendChild(row);
        });
        return table;

    }

document.querySelector("#employees").appendChild(buildTable(employeeList));
```

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Nope, that's the weird part :P

Comment: I find it a bit smelly that you try to save instances of Employees as strings...not sure what is saved in the localStorage and whether you can use them correctly afterwords... It might be better to store plain text and have a function that parses those data and transform them into Employees again... Dont see any other reason why localStorage wont work...

Comment: `localStorage.getItem("Employee") == null` will no longer be the case after you run this once, so changing the emails, or adding employees or the like does nothing until you clear localStorage. You can do this by calling `localStorage.setItem("Employee", null);` or by using the dev tools (F12, etc)